Aggregating data by month issues
I'm working on a project for school where I need to aggregate data to answer a business question. I'll change it a bit so I don't get in trouble with the school, but lets say I have a table that lists the date a car was purchased and the color. I'm trying use that to make a table that has month, color, and total purchased of that color in that month. I think I'm mostly there, but I'm getting the total of all preceding months as well (January is fine, February shows Jan+Feb totals).
Here's my query:
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM purchase_date) AS month, color, COUNT(color) AS total
FROM sales_table
GROUP BY month, color
ORDER BY month, total DESC

I'm very much a beginner at SQL and would appreciate any advice, or even just a pointer to a good resource/tutorial that could help with this.

Can you provide some sample data (MWE)? Tbh, the query looks fine to me.. (You might want to need COUNT(*) instead of COUNT(color), but this makes no difference if the color is not nullable, and you also might want to group not only by month but possibly also including the year - but that is just a guess. Both should not result in the effect you are reporting.)

I don't even know what's going on now, the lab environment crashed, I reloaded it so I could get some mock up data for you, and when I ran it again its working as I expected. Sorry to have wasted your time, I guess

If you group data by month, you must also group it by year (respectively, if you group by (ISO) week, you must group by isoyear), otherwise you will end up grouping all the data from different years together. This is a common mistake; it is possible your school is trying to make you realize this with datasets tailored to look like data from different months is grouped together. On that note, if you you had a WHERE clause to filter e.g. on only the most recent year, I would argue you still need to group by year to avoid surprises when editing your query.

Yep, you were close.  Try
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM purchase_date) AS month, color, COUNT(1) AS total
FROM sales_table
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM purchase_date), color
ORDER BY month, total DESC

You have to use the expression itself in the GROUP BY clause (not the column alias) because the column 'month' doesn't exist yet at that point - but it does by the time it gets to the ORDER BY clause.
